# How to know the file is uploaded to dropbox or not

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Is there any way to know that a file is uploaded from an android device to the dropbox using sync api for dropbox? And if yes then how can I know the number of files uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`getSyncStatus`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile.getSyncStatus) on the file to monitor its progress. (Use [`addListener`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile.addListener) to get notifications of its status change.)

The [`DbxFileStatus`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileStatus) you get back from `getSyncStatus` has a `pending` field that will tell you whether the file is being uploaded or downloaded and progress (how many bytes have been transferred).

So essentially, you'll monitor each file that you write to see its progress as it's uploaded.